# How to initialize an RDD with n number of pairs of zero

Tags: scala, apache-spark, initialization, rdd

I want to initialize an RDD which contains n number of pairs of zero.
For example: `n = 3`, the expected result will be:

```
init: RDD[(Long, Long)] = ((0,0), (0,0), (0,0))
```

I need to initialize n number of pairs of RDDs. It could be thousands, or hundred thousand, even millions.
If I do it using for loop with Scala code, then transform it to an RDD. It will take a long time.

```
var init: List[(Long, Long)] = List((0,0))
for(a <- 1 to 1000000){
  init = init :+ (0L,0L)
}
val pairRDD: RDD[(Long, Long)] = sc.parallelize(init)
```

Can anybody give me direction how to do it

Comment: I'm curious about the use case. Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `spark.range` to initialize the rdd in parallel from start:

```
val rdd = spark.range(1000000).map(_ => (0, 0)).rdd
// rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[13] at rdd at <console>:23

rdd.take(5)
// res9: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((0,0), (0,0), (0,0), (0,0), (0,0))
```